# Interpretation of TEM pictures of atoms

Tags: atoms, microscopy, nanoscience

I've got a question about images taken with Transmission Electronic Microscope. Are the images we find on scientific papers and articles on the web the negative of the real image appearing on the phosphorescent screen of the microscope?

This is the public image:
http://www.tc.umn.edu/~manno005/graphene%20TEM.bmp

Is this the original image seen in the TEM?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55cGPrY7DuedjVIN1VmYUgzQjA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Without any further details, it will be hard to get a good answer. Could you e.g. post an example image or a link to one?

Comment: Given the myriad image modes of a TEM, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @engineer I've added two images: the first graphene molecules from the web the second modified by me as the theorised real image on the fluorescent screen at the bottom of the TEM

Comment: Hi Caby. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.